# How to combine a list of lists with a second list into a single list of lists?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have two lists of same length:

```
l1 = [['a','b'],['b','c'],[]]
l2 = [0,1,3]
```

How do I make a list `l3` from these two lists such that:

```
l3 = [['a','b',0],['b','c',1],[3]]
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself and came across a problem?

Comment: Hint: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) 'em

Comment: If you want to get creative, you could do `map(list.append, l1, l2)`.  It will change `l1` in place (and return a pointless list of `None`s).

Comment: @Leb yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: here's the answer

```
l1 = [['a','b'],['b','c'],[]]
l2 = [0,1,3]
l3 = [l1[i] + [x] for i, x in enumerate(l2)]
```

Comment: Note that `enumerate` works well in this case, but does fail if the lists are of different lengths. Especially if `l2` is the longer length.

Comment: If the lists are not always the same length he can just use `zip` ;)

Comment: @NathanielFord tried enumerate on lists of diff lengths, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l3 = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Zip creates a list of tuples of the form `('item from first list', 'item from the second list')`. Then it's just a matter of moving through that list and merging them. (The `x+[y]` part of the for-comprehension above.)